# React Login Button Not Working (express server)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, authentication, database-connection

This is my button by which I am trying to authenticate my user located in MongoDB database

```
<Form.Item>
    <Button type="submit" htmlType="submit" className="login-form-button" onClick={handleSubmit}
    >
    Log in
    </Button>
</Form.Item>
```

This my handle submit function which is called when button in clicked

```
const handleSubmit = async (e)=>
{

  e.preventDefault();
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/login",{
    method: "POST",
    mode:'no-cors',
    headers: {
      'content-type':'application/json'
    },
    body:  JSON.stringify({email:credentials.email, password: credentials.password})

  });
  console.log(response.body);
  const json = await response.json();

  if(json.success){
    window.history.push("/");
  }
}
```

This is my express code which I am trying to connect with my react front end but repeatedly showing bad request

```
app.post("/login", function(req, res){

  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  });

  req.login(user, function(err){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
        res.redirect("/secrets");
      });
    }
  });

});
```

I am trying to connect my react front end with express server and expecting to get authenticated in case of login

Comment: Can you post the full React component code?

Answer (score 0):

Your button in the html is typed as `<Button>` with a capital. It should be lowercase `<button type="submit" htmlType="submit" className="login-form-button" onClick={handleSubmit}>Log in</button>`

I think this should work.

If not what error are you getting in the console?

Comment: POST http://localhost:5000/login 400 (Bad Request)                                                                Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (at Login.js:28:1)
    at handleSubmit (Login.js:28:1)                                                                                                            I am getting these errors with or without using Button